# Floating point exception CS50 readability assignment

Tags: c, cs50

I'm facing some problems regarding the Floating point exception error because previously when i printed the variables individually so i wasn't sure what went wrong. Down below is the code i have written so far. I'm not sure what cause the error as i am pretty sure i'm not dividing by zero.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cs50.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //promt user for text 
    string n = get_string("Text: ");
    int sumletters = 0; 
    int sumdots = 0;
    int sumspaces = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen (n); i++ )
    {
        if (n[i] >= 'A' && n[i] <= 'z')
        {
           sumletters = sumletters + 1; 
        }

        if (n[i] == ' ')
        {
            sumspaces = sumspaces + 1;
        }

        if (n[i] == '.' || n[i] == '?' || n[i] == '!' )
        {
            sumdots = sumdots + 1;   
        }

        float L = sumletters / (sumspaces / 100); 
        float S = sumdots / (sumspaces / 100); 
        int index = round ((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8); 

        if (index < 1)
        {
            printf ("Before grade 1\n");
        }
        {
            printf ("Grade 16+\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf ("Grade %i", index);
        }
    }
printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: `sumspaces / 100` is an integer division, so I wouldn't be surprised if the result of that could end up as 0 when you don't expect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part at fault:

```cpp
sumletters / (sumspaces / 100)
```

`sumspaces / 100` uses integer division so it will almost always be 0. You can refactor your code to use floating point division by simply distributing the division:

```cpp
sumletters / sumspaces * 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The below is integer division and the quotient is often zero as `int` math discards the fraction.

```
int sumspaces;
...
sumspaces / 100
```

The below can result in `int` division of 0.

```
int sumletters;
...
//           v---------------v might be 0 
sumletters / (sumspaces / 100);
```

> Floating point exception error  ...  i am pretty sure i'm not dividing by zero.

For various reason of a common error handler, `int` division by zero may be reported as a floating point exception.

---

As with many operations were the result  type is not in the operation, but only the assignment, such problems are common.

Instead, insure the math uses the destination type.

```
//                        v---------------v int division                       
// float L = sumletters / (sumspaces / 100); 

float L = sumletters / (sumspaces / 100.0f); 
//                     ^------------------^ At least float division
```

---

Aside: No good reason to use `float` types here, just use `double`.
Notice that code uses `double` math, and not `float` math in:

```
//         v----v         v---v        v--v  double constants
   round ((0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8)
// ^---^                                     double function
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) it worked by changing my variables on the top of the code to floats.